# Why do some spacing commands work correctly after end commands, and others don't?

Tags: verbatim

Why is it that

```
\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim
\end{verbatim}\bigskip
```

will work without errors, but if I changed the ending line to

```
\end{verbatim}\\[1\baselineskip]
```

I'll get errors?

Am I misunderstanding a basic concept of LaTex or?

Comment: Was that supposed to be `\\[1\baselineskip]`?

Comment: The error you get is `There's no line here to end` which should be self explaining: `\end{verbatim}` ends a paragraph and ``\\`` is not legal between paragraphs. I'd place `\bigskip` (or `\vspace{\baselineskip}`, if you prefer) below `\end{verbatim}`, not on the same line. But why would you want a big space below the verbatim text?

Comment: I have the feeling that you might be interested in package `parskip`. Possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`verbatim` is a display environment so after it you are in vertical (par) mode so you can use vertical spacing commands such as `\bigskip` (although you should almost never need to do this, the correct spacing should be specified in your class file).

Conversely `\\` is a command to be used in *horizontal* (LR) mode it forces a break *in the current line*.  There is no current line at that point so you get an error. Use of `\\` outside tables is almost always incorrect even when it doesn't generate an error.

Comment: Outside tables _and equations_ surely?

Comment: @IanThompson yes well outside alignments